# iOS set text color in a view's drawrect

Tags: ios, uiview, nsstring, drawrect

I have code that does custom rendering inside of a drawRect method in a UIView subclass. I am trying to render text out using `[NSString drawInRect]` which works great, however it always shows up in white. After much googling and browsing SO I have no been able to find out how to change the color of a text. Any advice would be great.

**Edit**
Below is the snippet of code inside my drawRect implementation

```
if(self.state != UIControlStateHighlighted)
{
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 2), 3.0, shadowColor);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    [title drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20]];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: I assume the `context` here was retrieved with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`?

Comment: BTW, `state` is actually a bitfield. You should be testing `if ((self.state & UIControlStateHighlighted) == 0)`

Comment: That is correct. The view renders properly with everything I pass to the context, it's just the text doesn't change it's color.

Comment: Just for kicks, what if, before the `-drawInRect:`, you try `[[UIColor colorWithCGColor:color] set];`?

Comment: Where exactly would I call that? Since I don't actually call the method.

Comment: Before the `[title drawInRect:...]` is what I meant

Comment: That did the trick. Why would this work and not individually calling 'setFill' or 'setStroke'?

Answer (score 7):

Before drawing text, you have to set the color. Try this,

```
[[UIColor blackColor] set]; 
[title drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried changing the current fill color?

```
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];
[string drawInRect:rect withFont:font];
```

Comment: I've tried setting the fill and the stroke to various colors and still all I get is white text.